# How to end a thread or join it to the main thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, thread-safety

Simplified, I start a number of background threads (this is the original method), when they complete their work, they raise an event, in that event they call the original method.

When the event is raised, it runs under the thread that raised it. Before I call the original method from within that event, I'd like to join back to the main thread (or join back in within the original method). Thus avoiding threads that can create more threads.

I guess I'm worried about the original threads never being garbage collected as they have called more threads? Will this be the case? and how can I make sure the thread has finished?

Note that I ensure only x number of threads can run at anyone time.

Comment: Having read some more, I don't think this will be a problem as it is all handled automatically. But I decided not to delete the question for a while in case someone had something interesting to say about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threads will be independent. To push work between them you need either a basic synchronised queue, or something like the Control.Invoke method.

To wait until *anothe* thread has exited, you can use:

```
otherThreas.Join();
```

But in many ways the event approach is cleaner. But the ever will be on the other thread, so you may well need to switch back (for example) to a UI thread as mentioned above.

Comment: When you say the UI thread, do you mean the main thread - this is a class library that may eventually run out of a windows service.

Comment: @MrShoubs - well, there isn't really a "main" thread - there isn't anything special about the entry-point thread except that it gets created first. I would propose you probably want the primary thread to service a work queue in that case, though...

Comment: That's a good comment for two reasons - my perspective was slightly wrong in thinking it was a main thread, and also that is exactly what I'm doing - the primary thread holds and maintains a queue (sync locked of course). I don't have .net 4 so I can't use it's new concurrent queue :( (also all my threads are background as I told them to be.)